# INDEX named ranges using COUNTA slowing performance

Tags: excel, performance, indexing, range, named

I have a workbook with approximately 100 named ranges set up the following way

```
=$A$1:Index($A:$A,counta($A:$A))
```

Within the workbook there are about 200,000 formulas that reference these named ranges. Due to the non-volatile nature of the INDEX function entering data in cell that do not reference a named range is very fast. The problem arises when data is entered into a cell that causes a recalculation of the affected named ranges, performance is hindered (1-5 second lag).

I've attempted to change all named ranges to the following

```
=$A$1:Index($A$1:$A$50000,counta($A$1:$A$50000))
```

but this has not helped. Is there a way to improve performance?

Notes:

- Performance is instantaneous when entering data into the workbook without triggering a recalculation of the named ranges.
- Careful care was given when developing the 200,000 formulas to ensure volatile functions used only when necessary (Most are SUMIFs with at most 6 condition pairs)
- There is no conditional formatting in the workbook
- There are no macros running in the background
- This is the only workbook open.
- File format is XLSM.
- File size: 3000KB

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the values being added to column A numeric, textual, or mixed?

Comment: Do you run your formula once, then make adjustments? Could you perhaps copy/paste as value all of the results, except one?  Then, you can edit all you want, and still keep the formula to update the sheet later.

Comment: You do not need those named ranges for `SUMIFS()`. You can select the entire column.

Comment: You say that "volatile functions used only when necessary". What are those volatile functions? Do they also reference these defined ranges?

Comment: Here is an example of the volatile functions used

=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((lkupBU_account=$B6)*lkupBU_BPT=$C6)*lkupBU_monthNumber))

This extracts the largest month number for a particular account and BPT in a lookup array. These do reference some named ranges.

Comment: @AdamCarter How many of these 200K formulas are being recalculated at any given time? Over how much data? How intensive are the formulas? Have you considered using Pivot Tables to replace the `SUMIFS()`? Is simply using manual calculation an option?